# Is there anyway to see properties / methods from Super class in IntelliJ directly on the Child class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Imagine I have a class like:

```
Class A extends B{

}
```

Now imagine class B has a method

```
foo();
```

Now in the IDE, when I am working on A.java, is it possible to see something like this:

```
Class A extends B{

    foo(){ // possibly in light gray and not editable / clickable.
    }  

}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry it seemed like a duplicate. I found a very similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way, it seems, is to use the **Structure** tab.

- With the child class open, click on the Structure tab (by default it's on the bottom left).
- When it's open, click the gear menu, and select **Group Methods by Defining Type**.  This will make things a lot clearer for you in a moment.
- Then, click the gear menu once more, and select **Show Inherited**.

You'll see something that looks a little like this:

[image]

My `Trainer` class has a method `toString()` which is inherited.

Answer (score -1):

It's a roundabout way to do it, but you can use the code generation tool and go to override methods. On linux and windows the hotkey is `ctrl + insert` and I believe it's `command + n` on macs. Then just click override methods and that should show you what you want.

Comment: Well this overrides the methods. I only want them to see, I do not want to override the methods.

Comment: @KorayTugay then just see them, and don't override them. As I said it was a roundabout way. I'm not sure of a way to jump directly to them if that's what you meant.

Comment: If the methods are included in the class, how can I not override them?